# Excel SQL to work in PowerPoint to select and resize picture

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I have this code in Excel, however I need the same thing to work in Powerpoint but I can't get it to work.

```
Sub Macro1()
    ' Macro1 Macro
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert("C:\Users\BobDylan\Pictures\Prince Symbol.jpg" _
        ).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 45
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 27
    Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 1.2272727273, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
    Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 1.2272727273, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
    Range("K16").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: sorry Chris new to here

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little something to get you started:

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddPicture "C:\Users\BobDylan\Pictures\Prince Symbol.jpg", msoFalse, msoTrue, 10, 10, 100, 100
```

**Update**

Added after your question

```
Sub test()
    Dim TargetSlide As Slide
    Dim pptLayout As CustomLayout

    Set pptLayout = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).CustomLayout

    Set TargetSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides.AddSlide(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count, pptLayout)
    TargetSlide.Shapes.AddPicture "C:\Users\BobDylan\Pictures\Prince Symbol.jpg", msoFalse, msoTrue, 10, 10, 100, 100
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Sam, is there a way to add a specific slide to add the pic too?

Comment: One last piece of the puzzle. I now need 2 pics sent to each slide and moved to the correct place. I also need the code to determine if its landscape set to one size and if its portrait set to another. I appreciate all your help.

Comment: I leave that last piece for you to figure out.

Comment: trust me I have been trying, but no joy at all

Comment: ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight/ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth ... if > 1, it's portrait, if < 1, it's landscape, if 1, it's square.